2x2 blocks in the QZ algorithm
How are the $2\times2$ blocks supposed to be diagonalized in the QZ-Algorithm? Taking the matrix pencil (A,B) and finding it's generalized Hessenberg decomposition (H,R) for which $\exists Q,Z \in \mathbb{O(n)}$ such that $$ Q' * A * Z = H , \quad  Q' * B * Z = R$$ where $H$ is upper Hessenberg and $R$ upper triangular. While performing the QZ-algorithm, I'm implementing deflation steps for both matrices. What am I supposed to do in the case where I have a full $2\times2$ block of H (which I'd like to reduce to upper-triangular) and it's respective $2\times2$ upper-triangular block of R? Am just supposed to leave it be?
Because I can't perform it's Schur decomposition (like in the QR case), without destroying R's upper-triangular form, right?
